# Developing Xamarin Project on different PCs

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have recently begun creating my first xamarin project on my laptop and it builds and runs fine with no errors. When I try and run the same project on my desktop I am getting 6 error messages and errors through parts of my code.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  15  Active
Error   CS0115  'MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle)': no suitable method found to override   MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  17  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'TabLayoutResource' does not exist in the current context  MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  19  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'ToolbarResource' does not exist in the current context    MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  20  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  23  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'LoadApplication' does not exist in the current context    MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MainActivity.cs  32  Active
```

I'm also getting these warnings as well.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1608  Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 23.3.0 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2.1 was resolved.   MealMateApp.Android J:\MealMateApp\MealMateApp\MealMateApp.Android\MealMateApp.Android.csproj   1   
Warning MSB3106 Assembly strong name "C:\Users\Jay\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(\). MealMateApp C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2110    
Warning MSB3106 Assembly strong name "C:\Users\Jay\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(\). MealMateApp C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2110    
Warning MSB3106 Assembly strong name "C:\Users\Jay\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.1.0.697729\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(\). MealMateApp C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  2110
```

Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: One of the reason can be you have a reference to assembly Xamarin.Forms from `C:\Program files (x86)` and you have different version of Visual Studio, e.g.Community and Professional. This caused environment cannot find assembly. So you can go to your Dependencies-Assemblies section and see if exclamation mark presents near assembly name. If yes - delete assembly and add it again from the correct path. Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this problem permanently, so you will need to repeat this process every time when you move your solution between PCs.

Comment: Try deleting manually all `/bin` & `/obj` folders and try to rebuild

Comment: Restore NuGet packages

Comment: @Cheesebaron this worked for me. Thanks :)